# Passing table as parameter to Web Service

Tags: web-services, web

I was in a situation to pass the table row as the parameter to Web Service.
Anyone can explain me how can i achieve it?

Comment: Are you talking about Asp.Net?  If so, just do it.

Comment: Passing Data object as parameter in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "table row", I'm assuming a row in a table? If that's the case it is probably easiest to put that into an array and pass that to the web service. (Given that a table is essentially a two dimensional array and you're just plucking a single array out of it.)